# Zend autoloader not working from PHP config

Tags: php, php.ini, zend-framework

Is the PHP config file (php.ini) supposed to have something in it that will enable Zend Autoloader support? Cause I am using it in my application and on one server and it's not working (it says it can't find the file in `require_once()`) and on another server it's working perfectly.

Any help on this? Thanks.